# How to automatcally arrange images of different size in an "organic" fashion?

Tags: images, adobe-indesign

I have a few hundred images that need to be presented as part of a report. These images have different sizes and orientations (portrait or landscape), and multiple images can belong to a single "group" (they are images of plant specimens and there is more than one picture per specimen).

Due to the large number of images, I'm looking for a way to easily and automatically sort these images in an "organic"/natural or aesthetically pleasing fashion. I was thinking of a layout similar to your typical news app:
[image]
[image]

Just that I would have each frame as a full image, without text.

My idea is to make a 3x3 grid on each page of the report, and then using that "news app" layout to arrange the images.So larger images would occupy 2 or 3 cells of the grid, either vertically or horizontally, whether they are landscape or portrait, respectively.

Is there some program, application, script, etc. that could help me with this?

I do have access to InDesign, though I'm not really familiar with it. I say this because ID, being a publishing application, is the most likely to have this functionality, even if its through some script or extension.

Any help is much appreciated. :)

Comment: I would be interested in a solution. Have you found anything?